# How to make multiline TextInput shrink when deleting lines (React-Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, textinput, react-native-textinput

I have a custom multiline TextInput which grows/expands automatically to fit its content:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
    
    export function MyInput() {
        const [value, setValue] = useState('Sample')
        const [height, setHeight] = useState(56)
        return (
            <TextInput
                value={value}
                onChangeText={text => {
                    setValue(text)
                }}
                onContentSizeChange={event => {
                    setHeight(Math.max(56, event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height))
                }}
                multiline
                style={{
                    padding: '16px',
                    height: height + 'px'
                }}
            />
        )

}
```

However if it is already expanded to multiple lines and I delete its content, onContentSizeChange does not fire and the empty lines are not removed automatically. Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to shrink the input:

1. Add a border to the `TextInput` in the style props, e.g.:

```
borderWidth: 0.5, // any value is required
borderColor: "transparent"
```

2. Use `onChange` callback instead of the `onContentSizeChange` in the `TextInput` (originally posted [here](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/795#issuecomment-733610960)):

```
onChange={(e) => {
  e.nativeEvent.target.style.height = 0;
  e.nativeEvent.target.style.height = `${e.nativeEvent.target.scrollHeight}px`;
}}
```